# Can a dereferenced pointer point to the same address as the pointer itself?

Tags: c, pointers

I've written the following code and I don't understand how does it work.

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct {
    char s[100];
} MyStruct;

void teste(MyStruct *mS) {
    scanf("%s", mS->s);
    printf("%s\n", mS->s);

    scanf("%s", &(mS->s));
    printf("%s\n", mS->s);

    printf("%p\n", mS->s);
    printf("%p\n", &(mS->s));
}

int main(void) {
    MyStruct a;
    teste(&a);
    return(0);
}
```

When compiling, I get the (expected) warning that:

```
gut.c: In function ‘teste’:
gut.c:11:8: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat=]
    scanf("%s", &(mS->s));
```

However, when I run the code, `mS->s` and `&(mS->s)` behave as they're equal!

```
aaa
aaa
bbb
bbb
0x7ffc0fab39c0
0x7ffc0fab39c0
```

And both the pointer and it's dereferenced version are actually equal! How does this happen? Is this undefined behavior? I'm using GCC 5.3.1, with the only flag being `-Wall`.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: TL/DR, but the answer for the topic: `void* p; p=&p;`

Comment: "How does this happen?" - Your code is buggy?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Which hardly is of much use (if we keep that at beginner level;-)

Comment: The address of a `char` array happens to be the same as the address of the first `char` in it (though the types of the pointers differ).